# How to convert a Map ByteString ByteString to Map String String and print it

Tags: haskell, type-conversion, maps

How would someone convert a Map of `ByteString:ByteString` to a Map `String:String`? I tried the following:

```hs
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.ByteString.UTF8 as BSU

type Key   = ByteString
type Valye = ByteString
type DB    = Map.Map Key Valye

printMap :: IO ()
printMap = do
    -- db exists to this point and is of type DB
    mapM_ putStrLn $ Map.map BSU.toString db
```

This will result in a printable value, but only my values are printed not my keys...
I know there is also `Map.mapKeys` which would give me the keys, but how do I obtain both and print them like this?

```
k0: v0
k1: v1
k2: v2
```

Comment: You can not just convert a `ByteString` to a `String`, since that requires an "encoding".

Comment: I encoded them from String to ByteString with `BSU.fromString` and saved them in the Map. `BSU.toString` gives me the values, so this have to work I guess?

Comment: Ah, that's UTF8 then

Comment: You can probably `fromList . map (both BSU.toString) . toList`?

Comment: I tired that, but got no usable result. I got it working with the approved Answer.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want `printMap = print db`...?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. However, this could have worked :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Map` itself isn't a functor, only `Map k` for some key type `k`, which is why `mapM_` only operates on your values. Instead, work with the list of key/value pairs returned by `Map.toList`.

```
mapM_ (\(k, v) -> ...) (Map.toList db)
```